# Flash based websites

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi I come from a background of 1 year of HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP/MySQL and recently Flash based websites atracted my atention.I know that I have to learn Actionscript 3.0 and Flash program to create this type of websites but what other Technologies do I need to learn?

And also can you recomend some good books for each technology?

Comment: Adobe themselves are actually discouraging this particular use of Flash in the modern day given that iOS Safari does not support plugins.  For general-purpose websites, stick with the stack you're already familiar with.

If you want to get into browser-based games that support GPU enabled 3D graphics on Desktop/Laptop targets, or cross-compiled native apps for iOS and Android that aren't too performance-sensitive, then by all means give Flash a shot... just know that "flash websites" are quickly falling out of fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @scriptocalypse mentioned Flash for general purpose sites might not be the best fit, however Flash is still widely used for Rich Internet Applications (RIAs) and games.

Most seriously development with ActionScript is done with Flash Builder which may or may not include using the Flex framework to get a jumpstart on the UI. So I'd say definitely take a look at adding Flex to your list of things to learn.

Any large scale Flash/Flex app can get pretty unwieldy without a micro-framework, Adobe has pushed [Cairngorm](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm) but I personally prefer [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/), there's also [PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/) which I used before Robotlegs (I prefer RL because it uses native AS3 events, as well as dependency injection which is easier to test).

Speaking of testing (which is always a good idea), there's [FlexUnit](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexunit/FlexUnit) and [ASUnit](http://asunit.org/).

If you're looking to get into game development [Flixil](http://flixel.org/) and [PushButton](http://pushbuttonengine.com/) are popular frameworks.

The best programming book, ActionScript or otherwise, I've read is [Essential ActionScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526946) by Colin Moock. There's a RobotLegs book out there but the website docs are so good you might not need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could be interested in [AMFPHP](http://projects.silexlabs.org/?/amfphp#/php.remoting/what.is.amfphp). See [this sample](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Starting_with_AMFPHP-11947.html) from Adobe for start with it.